# SQL Nested Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables:

```
Student(sID, firstName, lastName, email, cgpa)
Course(cNum, name, dept, credit)
Offering(oID, cNum, dept, year, term, instructor)
Took(sID, oID, grade)
```

I'm trying to complete the question:

```
Find all courses for the term 2017F and the current enrolment
```

I currently have this query to grab the number of students enrolled in each course:

```
SELECT Took.oID, COUNT(*) AS enrolment
FROM Took
GROUP BY Took.oID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Nested inside of this statement to grab the correct courses that I want the enrolment counts for:

```
SELECT oID
FROM Offering
WHERE Offering.year = 2017
AND Offering.term = 'F'
```

Both of which are nested inside of this query to tie everything together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Offering.cNum, Course.name, (I WOULD LIKE COUNT(*) AS enrolment HERE)
FROM Offering NATURAL JOIN Course
WHERE Offering.oID IN (
            SELECT oID
            FROM Offering
            WHERE Offering.year = 2017
            AND Offering.term = 'F'
            AND oID IN (
                    SELECT Took.oID, COUNT(*) AS enrolment
                    FROM Took
                    GROUP BY Took.oID
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0))
GROUP BY Offering.cNum, Course.name;
```

My question is, how can I pass the resulting COUNT(*) AS enrolment from the furthest nested query to the initial query so that it can be displayed in the resulting projection? (This is homework)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Aside - consider renaming *Took* as this domain may not be clear 6 mos from now. Maybe *CoursesTaken* or *StudentCourses*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try to use a subquery in `from` with `JOIN` instead of `where` subquery.

Then you can get `count` column from the subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Offering.cNum, Course.name,t1.enrolment
FROM Offering 
JOIN (
    SELECT Took.oID, 
        COUNT(*) AS enrolment
    FROM Took
    GROUP BY Took.oID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
) t1 on t1.oID = Offering.oID
NATURAL JOIN Course
WHERE Offering.year = 2017 AND Offering.term = 'F'
```

Comment: This definitely pointed me in the right direction, and I can move on to fixing it up from here. Thank you! (I'll set the answer as accepted in 3 minutes - I have to wait)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT c.*
    , (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Took
        WHERE oID = o.oID
    ) AS theCount
FROM Course c
JOIN Offering o ON o.cNum = c.cNum
WHERE o.year = 2017 AND o.term = 'F'
```

Comment: This is really helpful. I didn't know that you could put nested queries directly in SELECT. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May be this

```
SELECT Course.name, Course.cNum, count(*) as enrolment
FROM Course
JOIN Offering ON Course.cNum = Offering.cNum
JOIN Took ON Offering.oID = Took.oID
WHERE Offering.year = 2017
AND Offering.term = 'F'
GROUP BY Course.name, Course.cNum
HAVING count(*) > 0;
```